# PNG compression for live wallpapers in Android

Tags: java, android, png, live-wallpaper, compression

I'm trying to create a live wallpaper in Android but am having trouble with the PNG that I use for the background. When I slide home screens the transition is very laggy. My background PNG is 1024x576px 96dpi 1.01MB photo. It also has a transparent region.

```
c.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.foreground),mX,mY,null);


c.translate(mX, 0f);
```

I use this code for loading and translating the PNG.

What's the best to compress this PNG, or do I need to code it differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jpg` instead http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html.

Comment: I can't use JPG because I need a region of the picture to be transparent. I tried with GIF instead, the results were the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. I was loading my PNG each time my wallpaper went into an animation loop, instead of loading it once when the surface is created.

```
fG =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.foreground);
```

This code should be in the onCreate() method. Stupid me!